# How could I get DefinePlugin to work with karma/istanbul?

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner

I'm using karma to run tests on my code, and they all work fine, but when I add nyc with babel-plugin-__coverage__, I get: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __DEVELOPMENT__`. However, this variable is set in my webpack.config.js:

```
plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DEVELOPMENT__: true
}));
```

So I'm not sure I totally understand how to fix this so I can run my karma tests with coverage.

Comment: I'm also stuck with this. I've read every guide I found trying to find an error :(

Comment: Totally different error: I was using Visual Studio, and it seems that you have to rebuild when changing webpack config.